# How to find the expected distance between a point consisting of two random variables and the origin?

Tags: normal-distribution

Let ($X_1, X_2$) be two independent standard normal random variables. Compute $E[\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}]$, the expected distance between ($X_1, X_2$) and the origin.

This is the question I need to solve. I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Use the polar coordinate trick that gives us the $\sqrt{2\pi}$ in the formula for the gaussian density function.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered on the Cross Validated site of the StackExchange community. Check out the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435675/expected-distance-between-x-y-where-both-x-and-y-are-standrd-normal-random-v).